# Problem with compiling fft using gcc

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

I have downloaded the source codes of Splash2 from [here](http://www.m5sim.org/dist/m5_benchmarks/v1-splash-alpha.tgz) and i tried to compile fft.c using gcc command on my own machine but i got this error :

`fft.c:62:28: fatal error: parmacs_config.h: No such file or directory`

I searched over the internet but couldn't find any useful solutions. Any idea ?

Comment: What was the command?

Comment: It simply states that it cannot find `parmacs_config.h`, this means that: it is an external package/3rd party software file and you are missing this package or didn't give the proper path to this file. Other reason is that you didn't specify the makefile options properly.

Comment: i have a makefile in that directory and i tried to run make command but this error shows up : unrecognized option ‘-non_shared’.
What should i do ?